# Always get "METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED" from App Store Connect API Post Requests

Tags: node.js, rest, app-store-connect, app-store-connect-api

I am working with App Store Connect API for the first time, from NodeJS (if that matters, but I also tried with curl).

I was able to authenticate and send GET requests with no problem, but when trying to send POST request I always get "METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED" error.

Is anyone able to send post request? specifically to "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/certificates", but I also tried the Profiles endpoint, and I got the same problem.

The docs claim its possible, but this error makes me feel something is not updated over there.

Any help will be very much appreciated!

**Some extra information:**

JWT Playload:

```
{
  iss:"KEY ISSUER",
  iat:Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
  exp:Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 10),
  aud:'appstoreconnect-v1',
  scope:[
    'POST /v1/certificates'
  ]
}
```

JWT Options:

```
{
  algorithm:'ES256',
  header:{
    alg:'ES256',
    kid:"KEY ID",
    typ:'JWT'
  }
}
```

Request Body(Before Stringify):

```
{
  data:{
    type:'certificates',
    attributes:{
      certificateType:'IOS_DISTRIBUTION',
      csrContent:"PEM CERT"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the scope. It doesn't support POST. If you remove the scope key it should work fine.

[image]

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests

Comment: You are a life saver! How could I miss that!